# How to use pouch-couch db in python postgresql application?

Tags: postgresql, couchdb, pouchdb, offlineapps

I am building a WEB (PWA) application which needs to run offline and should sync data whenever network is available. Current technology stack is  Postgresql and django.
For offline apps   Pouch db and couch db seems to be the first choice. But how exactly postgresql database should be used with Pouch db and couch db? What should be architecture and which library I have use to sync postgresql data to user's device

Comment: Couch/Pouch and Postgres are completely different and unrelated. If your app already uses Postgres, replacing it with Couch/Pouch, or perhaps harder, using both, will be a HUGE undertaking. There's no way to address this in SO post. It's basically a question of "How do redesign my entire application?" which is obviously well beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: @Sushant Danekar: do you find a solution? I have the same needs